# How much damage does the Jagged Ghost Blade block when not using a Transcendent Curse?

Tags: dark-souls

Ghosts pierce through your armor, inflicting massive damage. To block them, you need to use a curse, (2000 souls, which is a lot) or you can use a cursed weapon to block it, but obviously a dagger doesn't block as much as a shield.

I want to save my curses, and I have a cursed weapon that I could use to block: the Jagged Ghost Blade.

I want to know how well blocking with that particular dagger works compared to blocking with a curse, because if a ghost gets in 3 hits at my level I'm dead. Also, the ghosts have a critical attack. Can I block that?

Comment: Some people are going to take issue with the phrase "is it ok to..." as being opinion-based. What *exactly* are you asking? What would make it okay versus not okay?

Comment: Is it helpful to use the jagged ghost blade, does it work well enough so that i don't need to use a curse?

Comment: I don't play Dark Souls (tried it, didn't like it), so I'm coming from a perspective of relative ignorance. Unfortunately, people like to close things they don't understand, so it's best to make it clear. If someone simply answered the question in the title, and left deciding whether that was "worth it" or "okay" up to you, would that work?

Comment: ghosts pierce through your armor, inflicting massive damage, to block them, you need to use a curse, (2000 souls, which is a lot) or you can use a cursed weapon to block it, but obviously a dagger doesn't block as much as a shield.

Comment: i hope that clarified things a bit.

Comment: So you can't block with a  shield unless you use a curse? You're wanting an answer that compares blocking with the dagger and not using a curse to blocking with a shield while using a curse, then.

Comment: yes, but i want to know if blocking with that particular dagger is better, because if a ghost gets in 3 hits at my level you're dead. also the ghosts have a critical attack that i want to know if it can block.

Comment: I edited in the stuff you told me in comments. In the future, you should try to edit in this information yourself when asked for clarification. You don't get any credit for stuff in comments.

Comment: We could always use more interested and active users.

Comment: I find it fun to help other people, and the points system gives a certain satisfaction.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but ghosts drop curses at a pretty reasonable rate. If you use one curse to be able to fight them normally, odds are very good you're going to get at least one curse back from moving through the area.

Comment: If you level up a bit, 2000 souls really isn't that much. Also ghosts drop curses, as others have said.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a "Transcendent Curse" effectively curses *you*, so any equipment you use will be able to block, and inflict damage on the ghosts. This means that if you have a shield with 100(%) physical damage reduction, (as the ghost's damage is physical), then you block 100% of the damage.

If you have a cursed weapon, such as the Jagged Ghost Blade, or indeed the (Cursed) Greatsword of Artorias, this can block, or inflict damage on the ghosts. However, being primarily an offensive weapon, the defensive capabilities are far less impressive.

- Jagged Ghost Blade - 45% Physical Damage reduction
- Ghost Blade - 45% Physical Damage reduction
- Greatsword of Artorias (Cursed) - 60% Physical Damage reduction

Comment: how much damage does the other ghost blade do, i cant remember what its called, and do these weaons block the male ghost reacharound grab attack?

Comment: @Walker I'm not sure of the weapon you're talking about, but those are the only two cursed weapons in the game, that are effective in this field. As for the grab, it cannot be blocked - by any weapon or shield. However it can be easily avoided by moving toward thr attacker - as the arms stretch out to grab you, if you are not near the hands, the grab will miss.

Comment: there is also another cursed weapon that drops only from female ghosts, there are only two female ghosts in the game and they attack with lightning, it's just called the ghost blade, and thanks for the advice on the grab attack.

Comment: @Walker You should just go with Curses in my opinion, and if to you 2000 souls is a lot when you reach new londo, you probably took the wrong path somewhere :)

Comment: I'm exploring a bunch of different places at once, and it's not a lot but there's a lot of other good stuff you can do with 2000 souls.

Comment: @Walker I stand corrected. The other weapon you are referring to is the "Ghost Blade" which shares the exact same stats as the "Jagged Ghost Blade".

Comment: i understood that it's worse, 155 damage to 110.